# Is it possible to use @html.EditorFor with ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Is there anyway to use `@html.editorfor`and other helpers like that in an editor template when I'm looping through properties?

Please note that I'm using Kendo Grid. Kendo uses `Html.EditorForModel()` to generate edit and create modal windows. I don't want the default layout and also some properties should be displayed differently, with different elements for example. So, I'm trying to create custom editor templates for my models and render properties in the way I want them.

This is the Editor Template:

```
@using System.Collections
@model Models.ClassName

@{int i = 0;}
<div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
    @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
    {
        //filtering navigation and computational properties
        if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Z") || property.IsReadOnly))
        {
            continue;
        }
        switch (property.PropertyName)
        {
            case "pro3":
                @Html.Hidden(property.PropertyName, "-1")
                continue;
            case "LiIdPeriod":
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
                    @Html.DropDownList(property.PropertyName, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Years"], "Id", "Text"))
                </div>
                break;
            default:
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                @Html.Label(property.DisplayName, new { @for = property.PropertyName, @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
                @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
                break;
        }
        if (++i % 2 == 0)
        {
            @:</div><div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you do that and what are you trying to achieve? Just use `EditorForModel()` or `EditorFor(m => m)`

Comment: I have some reasons: 1. I'd like to format my forms differently. 2. I want to use different elements for different properties. Is there any better way?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give some examples of what you are trying to do. Using a `foreach` loop on `ModelMetadata.Properties` is an awful solution

Comment: I'd like to have a 2 column layout. Also, some properties are foreign keys and I want to show a dropdown list for them, And some of them should be hidden. Do you have any good example?

Comment: I know about the 2 column layout - you accepted my answer :) Why are you not just using the html helpers for each of your properties. If you want a dropdown, then use `@Html.DropDownListFor()`. I'm guessing your not understanding just how inflexible your attempt is, and you it will almost certainly write more code than the standard way of creating form controls

Comment: You mean I loop through properties and in my `switch` and decide about their type? That's what I'm doing for another class. And my problem with @html.*For is that they accept Linq expression and this question was supposed to be about that problem. Did I asked that bad? :)

Comment: What switch statement? A view should **never** have a switch statement! `EditorForModel()` and `EditorFor(m => m)` will effectively do what your `foreach` loop is attempting, but will do it correctly. Are you aware of `EditorTemplates`? Its hard to understand what your trying to achieve with this code. And if you want `EditorFor()` rather that `Editor()` then your code will not work

Comment: I usually try to remove the codes for brevity, but I'll update the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78271/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-akbari).